# Eclipse cannot find tld inside jar file

Tags: eclipse, jsp-tags, taglib, eclipse-kepler, tagfile

I have a jar file that contains some tag-files.

My `*.tag` files are inside `/META-INF/tags/` folder (jar)

I also have a `mytags.tld` inside `/META-INF/` folder (jar)

After pack all `war` project (with `mytags.jar` inside `WEB-INF/lib` folder), it works fine in JBoss. But Eclipse still cannot recognize the tag, getting the error `Can not find the tag library descriptor for "http://www.mycompany.com"`

Is there a way to Eclipse recognize my tags?

---

follow the sources:

**block.tag**

```
<%@tag description="Item do block" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>

<%@attribute name="id" required="true" %>
<%@attribute name="label" required="true" %>
<%@attribute name="description" required="false" %>
<%@attribute name="icon" required="false" %>

<div id="${id}" class="block">
    <div class="block-box ${icon}">
        <div class="label">
            <span>${label}</span>
        </div>
        <div class="description">
            ${description}
            <jsp:doBody></jsp:doBody>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**mytags.tld**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<taglib xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-jsptaglibrary_2_1.xsd"
    version="2.1">

    <description>My Tags</description>
    <display-name>MyTags</display-name>
    <tlib-version>1.0</tlib-version>
    <short-name>mytags</short-name>
    <uri>http://www.mycompany.com</uri>

    <tag-file>
        <name>block</name>
        <path>/META-INF/tags/block.tag</path>
    </tag-file>
</taglib>
```

**some.jsp**

```
<%@page contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1" pageEncoding="UTF-8" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://www.mycompany.com" prefix="mytags" %> <-- ECLIPSE MARKS ERROR HERE
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <title>Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <mytags:block id="users" label="Users" icon="user">
            <!-- some content -->
        </mytags:block>
    </body>
</html>
```

---

But everything works fine in JBoss. Only eclipse accuses error.

Thanks

Comment: Which *version* of Eclipse? And if you revalidate the JSP, does the message go away?

Comment: Eclipse Kepler. No, the message doesn't go away after revalidate the JSP

Comment: Is the project a Dynamic Web Project with the jar in its WebContent/WEB-INF/lib folder, or otherwise on the Java Build Path?

Comment: The project is a Dynamic Web Project, but the jars are referenced (in Java Build Path) to the maven repository. But I'm not using m2eclipse.

Comment: Are the jars physically readable by Eclipse?

Comment: yes, the jar is in my local maven repository. And I can find it in Package Explorer > Referenced libraries.

Comment: Sounds like this is worth a bug report then (https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=WTP%20Source%20Editing&component=jst.jsp&version=3.5). It certainly sounds like you've got everything set up in ways that should work.

Answer (score 1):

An existing bug report https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=330405 suggests correcting the error message to point to the JSP version 1.1 detected from web.xml as a reason for the outdated interpretation of the taglib URI.

This is confirmed by a JSP Tag Libraries document, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14014/taglibs.htm#i1014427:

> As first defined in the JSP 1.1 specification, the taglib directive of a JSP page can fully specify the name and physical location, within a WAR file structure, of the TLD file that defines a particular tag library, as in the following example:

```
<%@ taglib uri="/WEB-INF/oracustomtags/tlds/mytld.tld" prefix="oracust" %>
```

> [..] Alternatively, as also defined since the JSP 1.1 specification, the taglib directive can specify the name and application-relative physical location of a JAR file instead of a TLD file

Both of the above 2 conventions retired to a fallback mechanism since JSP 1.2 which introduced mapping tag definitions and uses through the arbitrary taglib uri strings, http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14099_19/web.1012/b14014/taglibs.htm#i1013109.

A recent JSP 2.1 spec documents the URI mapping in section JSP.7.3.2:

> The URI describing a tag library is mapped to a TLD resource path though a
>   taglib map, and a fallback interpretation that is to be used if the map does not
>   contain the URI. The taglib map is built from an explicit taglib map in web.xml
>   (described in Section JSP.7.3.3) that is extended with implicit entries deduced
>   from packaged tag libraries in the web application (described in
>   Section JSP.7.3.4), and implicit entries known to the JSP container. The fallback
>   interpretation is targetted to a casual use of the mechanism, as in the development
>   cycle of theWeb Application; in that case the URI is interpreted as a direct path to
>   the TLD (see Section JSP.7.3.6.2).